# Error on Ssh server in Debian 10 Buster

Tags: debian, ssh, sshd

Can't connect `sshd` in Debian 10 "Buster", catching errors as follows, while connecting:

```
$ ssh -p 2222 user@192.168.12.73
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Checking those services, got following errors:

```
● sshd.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-10-22 18:10:51 -03; 13min ago
  Process: 559 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 606 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2304)
   Memory: 2.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─606 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Oct 22 18:10:50 ffurtpc systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Oct 22 18:10:51 ffurtpc sshd[606]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Oct 22 18:10:51 ffurtpc sshd[606]: error: Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.
Oct 22 18:10:51 ffurtpc systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Oct 22 18:14:26 ffurtpc sshd[1514]: Connection closed by authenticating user friedrich 192.168.12.73 port 49880 [preauth]
Oct 22 18:23:45 ffurtpc sshd[1583]: fatal: Missing privilege separation directory: /run/sshd
```

Already tried to manage it with `xinetd` package, setting it to port 2222, while OpenBSD Secure Shell server keeps listening port 22, as follows:

```
● xinetd.service - LSB: Starts or stops the xinetd daemon.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/xinetd; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-10-22 18:10:55 -03; 15min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 722 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/xinetd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2304)
   Memory: 4.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/xinetd.service
           └─755 /usr/sbin/xinetd -pidfile /run/xinetd.pid -stayalive -inetd_compat -inetd_ipv6

Oct 22 18:10:56 ffurtpc xinetd[755]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/echo-udp [file=/etc/xinetd.d/echo-udp] [line=26]
Oct 22 18:10:56 ffurtpc xinetd[755]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/servers [file=/etc/xinetd.d/servers] [line=14]
Oct 22 18:10:56 ffurtpc xinetd[755]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/services [file=/etc/xinetd.d/services] [line=13]
Oct 22 18:10:56 ffurtpc xinetd[755]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/sshd [file=/etc/xinetd.d/sshd] [line=13]
Oct 22 18:10:56 ffurtpc xinetd[755]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/time [file=/etc/xinetd.d/time] [line=16]
Oct 22 18:10:56 ffurtpc xinetd[755]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/time-udp [file=/etc/xinetd.d/time-udp] [line=28]
Oct 22 18:10:56 ffurtpc xinetd[755]: 2.3.15.3 started with libwrap loadavg labeled-networking options compiled in.
Oct 22 18:10:56 ffurtpc xinetd[755]: Started working: 1 available service
Oct 22 18:14:22 ffurtpc sshd[1512]: Connection closed by authenticating user friedrich 192.168.12.73 port 35954 [preauth]
Oct 22 18:23:43 ffurtpc sshd[1582]: fatal: Missing privilege separation directory: /run/sshd
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had similar error here, it looks that `sshd` is failing to create `/run/sshd` directory while booting up, so managed here to do it via script, as follows:

Create a `sshddir` script with following content in `/etc/init.d/`:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          sshddir
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $network
# Should-Start:      $network
# Default-Start:     3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 2 6
# Short-Description: Sshd /run/sshd Directory
# Description:       Intended to create /run/sshd directory for Sshd.
### END INIT INFO

mkdir -p /run/sshd

chmod -R 755 /run/sshd
```

`$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/sshddir`

`$ sudo update-rc.d sshddir defaults`

That way, may reboot and access it.

Comment: Didn't worked here, only could run it via `systemd` proper service.

Comment: That stoped working here too after a few reboots. May please post it as answer?

Comment: That started to generate error here too, already managed to repair it, have a look. Occurred that was missing `Required-Start:`, `Required-Stop:`, `Should-Start:` entrances and needn't `$ sudo update-rc.d sshddir enable`, the `$ sudo update-rc.d sshd defaults` already generates proper symlinks on runlevels directories.

Answer (score 2):

Just create `sshddir.service` file in `/etc/system/systemd/` with following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run Sshd Directory Creator
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshddir
ExecReload=/usr/bin/sshddir
Restart=always
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshddir.service
```

Then:

2a    - `$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

2b    - `$ sudo systemctl enable sshddir`

But is needed, first, remove `SysVinit` managed file:

1a    - `$ update-rc.d sshddir disable`

1b    - `$ update-rc.d sshddir remove`

Only then, reboot machine.

Looks like somehow `systemd` removes `/run/sshd` folder on boot up, generating error.

Comment: Just managed to run it via `SysVinit` itself, check it out up there.